# Sqlite first query taking too long in Windows XP due to caching?

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, caching, system.data.sqlite

It looks like theres a problem when using SQLite in Windows where the first query on a relatively large dataset takes a significant amount of time longer than subsequent queries. I'm sure its not related to the query structure.

From other posts on the internet, it looks like this may be related to a caching issue in Windows (where it attempts to cache large files on startup), however, I have not been able to verify this. Also I cannot find sufficient information in the SQLite documentation to work out if its a problem with SQLite rather than windows.

I have two questions relating to this:

- Can anyone confirm that there is a problem with Windows with large files that may be having an impact on the SQLite databases (the file extension is not ".db") & suggest some workarounds?
- Is there anything going on within SQLite itself that may explain the first query being so much slower than the rest.

Answer (score 3):

You may find [this message thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg20213.html) from the sqlite-users mailing list helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The caching isn't an "issue".  What is happening is that the first time a query is executed, the result is loaded into the cache and then returned.  On subsequent calls the results are pulled from the cache.

If caching were turned off *all* queries would take the same (longer) amount of time to return data.

That's the nature of database caching.

If the first query is taking too long, then you should look at ways to tune its performance.

Another cache is when DLLs are dynamically loaded.  If that's what you are observing, you could execute a query on application start.  That would slow down your app startup, but your first real query would be faster.